# Karma + Mocha with Typescript results `Can't find variable: require` or `Empty test suite`

Tags: typescript, karma-runner, karma-mocha, typescript1.6

My Karma config:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '.',
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
        files: ['test/**/*-test.js'],
        exclude: [],
        preprocessors: {
            '**/*.ts': ['typescript']
        },
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        singleRun: false,
        concurrency: Infinity,
        plugins: [ 'karma-*' ],
        client: {
            mocha: { ui: 'bdd' }
        },
        typescriptPreprocessor: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: false,
                target: 'es5',
                module: 'commonjs',
                removeComments: true
            },
            transformPath: function(path) {
                return path.replace(/\.ts$/, '.js');
            }
        }
    })
};
```

and test file

```
// test/app-test.ts
import chai = require('chai');

var expect = chai.expect;

describe('test', () => {
    it('should work', () => {
        expect(true).should.be.true;
    });
});
```

The result is

> Empty test suite.

When I change the `files: ['test/**/*-test.js'],` to `files: ['test/**/*-test.ts'],`, the result is:

> Can't find variable: require

The full source is in: https://github.com/Ridermansb/webpackKarmaAngularTypescriptStarter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Missing `typings` in `karma.config.js`
2. I use bdd style, so the test should be `true.should.be.true`.
3. No need to require chai in tests.

Fixed in commit [0a4a20c7558579f8c6910a6054e872f87ec97203](https://github.com/Ridermansb/webpackKarmaAngularTypescriptStarter/commit/0a4a20c7558579f8c6910a6054e872f87ec97203)